# How to turn on Apple Watch notifications for SMS messages?

Tags: notifications, watchos

I get notifications on my watch from iMessage(blue) but not sms (green).

This happens on watch 4 & 9 and at different watchOS revision.

Is this a bug (or feature) or configuration issue or perhaps a carrier issue?